# Why am I unable to download STS?

Tags: eclipse, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I don't know if this is a website bug or something, but I am unable to download STS from the official STS website! The link simply won't click.I Tried this over Chrome and Safari (via a different machine).

http://spring.io/tools/sts/all

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, is there a way to download over terminal? I need the full package with the latest version of Groovy and Grails.

Comment: try this http://www.grails.org/STS+Integration may be helpful :)

Comment: thanks, but that takes me back to the same link I have shared above. Thanks to whoever is marking this question as -1 without telling why... real helpful!

Comment: May be this question is not a programming related problem and off topic here

Comment: true, but we have `eclipse` and `sts` topics here on SO right..? they are not programming related either.

Comment: yes true.but they are for if we are using their API or something doing with them like configurations etc.But for asking about their website issues is a bit weired here.I hope you are getting my point

Comment: By the way their is no down vote on your question 0.o

Comment: Links don't work in Firefox either! You can see the links in the page source http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.4.0/dist/e4.3/spring-tool-suite-3.4.0.RELEASE-e4.3.1-macosx-cocoa-installer.dmg for Mac 4.3.1

Comment: @AtharvaJohri There are no up or down votes recorded on this question, so if there was a -1 the voter has withdrawn it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Grails and Groovy you probably want GGTS since it's preconfigured, and you can add whatever plugins you want since it's Eclipse. The direct download for Linux is http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.4.0/dist/e4.3/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.4.0.RELEASE-e4.3.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz and if you can't get that with a browser, you can use wget or curl from a shell.

Comment: Just read about it.. maybe exactly what I need. I exported my STS preferences from an older machine.. will they work in GGTS?

Comment: Sure, it's all Eclipse plus plugins